# Сравнение массива Python

Tags: python

```
r = [(None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None)]
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы если r состоит только из одних None, то выполнить задачу, иначе ничего не делать.

Answer (score 2):

```
r = [(None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None), (None, None, None, None, None)]

if not set(sum(r, ())) - {None}:
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает